# Python: CVXPY SolverError

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, cvxopt

Purpose: I am trying to use cvxpy in python to maximize the `dual_func`, however I get the below SolverError, I believe it may be `Variable`s having different dimensions, but cant seem to figure out the issue. I have tried using other solvers like ECOS, but to no avail. I am new to convex optimization, so would be great if someone can help point me in the right direction of the error in the code.

Problem: The code works in cvxpy version 0.4, but not in the latest cvxpy version, giving me the error:

```
SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['CVXOPT']) do not support the
cones output by the problem (SOC, ExpCone, PSD), or there are not enough 
constraints in the problem.
```

The `dual_func` is convex and is DCP, hence I am still not sure why it can't be solved.

Additional Question: Is is possible to use strict inequality constraints in cvxpy? The documentation states it is not possible as it does not make sense in the real world, however, I don't really understand why it is the case.

```
from cvxpy import *
alpha_k = Variable()
mu_k_1 = Variable(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list))))
mu_k_2 = Variable(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list))))
covar_k_1 = Variable(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list)), int(len(h_undl_list))), PSD=True)
covar_k_2 = Variable(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list)), int(len(h_undl_list))), PSD=True)

# fitting the first 1000 returns with normal GMM
from sklearn import mixture
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, max_iter=1000, tol=1e-7).fit(ret_df_period)
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, max_iter=500, tol=1e-7, weights_init=[0.2, 0.8]).fit(ret_df_period)

print('weights')
print(clf.weights_)

# sorting the values to the normal regime or the stressed regime
if clf.weights_[0] > clf.weights_[1]:
    alpha_k.value = clf.weights_[0]
    mu_k_1.value = clf.means_[0]
    mu_k_2.value = clf.means_[1]
    covar_k_1.value = clf.covariances_[0]
    covar_k_2.value = clf.covariances_[1]
else:
    alpha_k.value = clf.weights_[1]
    mu_k_1.value = clf.means_[1]
    mu_k_2.value = clf.means_[0]
    covar_k_1.value = clf.covariances_[1]
    covar_k_2.value = clf.covariances_[0]
```

```
iter_t = 3
N = ret_df_period.shape[0] #time step, e.g. return at t
K = 2

for t_iter in range(iter_t):
    q_k = [alpha_k.value, 1 - alpha_k.value]
    mu_sk_list = [np.array(mu_k_1.value).flatten(), np.array(mu_k_2.value).flatten()]
    covar_sk_list = [covar_k_1.value, covar_k_2.value]
    q_posterior_list = []
    q_posterior_map = {}
    
    
    # E-Step
    import math
    # marginal probability, lambda_k * multivariate_normal.pdf, returns a matrix with K rows, N columns
    mar_prob_list = np.zeros((K,N))
    for k_idx_temp in range(0, K):
        for j_temp in range(0, N):
            mar_prob_list[k_idx_temp, j_temp] = (q_k[k_idx_temp] * multivariate_normal.pdf(ret_df_period.iloc[j_temp].values, mean = mu_sk_list[k_idx_temp], cov = covar_sk_list[k_idx_temp]))
    
    # lambda_k_n, q_n, q_posterior_distribution, returns a matrix with K rows, N columns
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        for j in range(0, N):
            joint_prob_k = q_k[k_idx] * multivariate_normal.pdf(ret_df_period.iloc[j], mean = mu_sk_list[k_idx], cov = covar_sk_list[k_idx])
            q_posterior = joint_prob_k / np.sum(mar_prob_list[:, j])
            q_posterior_list.append(q_posterior)
        
        q_posterior_map[k_idx] = q_posterior_list
        q_posterior_list = []
    
    
    #####a priori after E-Step, i.e. M-Step
    # Empirical probability, returns the two lambda_sk values
    alpha_sk_list = []
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        alpha_sk = 0
        for j in range(0, N):
            alpha_sk += q_posterior_map[k_idx][j]
        alpha_sk_list.append(alpha_sk / N)
    alpha_sk_list[1] = 1 - alpha_sk_list[0]
        
    
    # Mean, returns two sets of means
    mu_sk_list = []
    weighted_xs_map = {}
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        weighted_xs_map[k_idx] = np.empty([int(len(h_undl_list)), N])
    
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        mu_sk = 0
        for j in range(0, N):
            weighted_x = (q_posterior_map[k_idx][j]) * ret_df_period.iloc[j].values
            mu_sk += weighted_x
            weighted_xs_map[k_idx][:, j] = weighted_x / alpha_sk_list[k_idx] # should divide twice of alpha_sk here? Come back and double check later!!!
        mu_sk_list.append(mu_sk / N / alpha_sk_list[k_idx])
    
    # Cov, returns two cov
    covar_sk_list = []
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        sum_covar = 0
        for j in range(0, N):
            w0_temp = (ret_df_period.iloc[j] - mu_sk_list[k_idx]).values
            w0_covar = np.outer(w0_temp, w0_temp)
            weighted_covar = (q_posterior_map[k_idx][j]) * w0_covar
            sum_covar += weighted_covar
        sum_covar = sum_covar / (alpha_sk_list[k_idx] * N)
        covar_sk_list.append(sum_covar)


    #####
    #information params
    n_sk_list = []
    for k_idx in range(0, K - 1):
        n_sk = np.log(alpha_sk_list[k_idx] / (1 - (np.sum(alpha_sk_list[: -1]))))
        n_sk_list.append(n_sk)
    
    m_sk_list = []
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        m_sk = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(covar_sk_list[k_idx]), mu_sk_list[k_idx])
        m_sk_list.append(m_sk)
    
    S_sk_list = []
    for k_idx in range(0, K):
        S_sk = np.linalg.inv(covar_sk_list[k_idx])
        S_sk_list.append(S_sk)
    
    
    alpha_sk_1 = Parameter(nonneg=True)
    alpha_sk_2 = Parameter(nonneg=True)
    n_sk_pr = Parameter()
    dim = Parameter(nonneg=True)
    m_sk_1 = Parameter(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list)),))
    m_sk_2 = Parameter(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list)),))
    alpha_sk_1.value = alpha_sk_list[0]
    alpha_sk_2.value = alpha_sk_list[1]
    n_sk_pr.value = n_sk_list[0]
    m_sk_1.value = m_sk_list[0]
    m_sk_2.value = m_sk_list[1]
    dim.value = int(len(h_undl_list))
    covar_k_tilde = Variable(shape=(int(len(h_undl_list)), int(len(h_undl_list))), PSD=True)
    
    
    dual_func = entr(alpha_k) + entr(1 - alpha_k) + \
    alpha_sk_1*0.5*log_det(covar_k_1) + alpha_sk_1*dim*0.5*log(2*np.e*np.pi) + alpha_sk_2*0.5*log_det(covar_k_1 + covar_k_tilde) + alpha_sk_2*dim*0.5*log(2*np.e*np.pi) + alpha_k*n_sk_pr + \
    alpha_sk_1*(mu_k_1.T)*m_sk_1 - alpha_sk_1*0.5*trace(covar_k_1*S_sk_list[0]) - alpha_sk_1*0.5*quad_form(mu_k_1, S_sk_list[0]) + \
    alpha_sk_2*(mu_k_1.T)*m_sk_2 - alpha_sk_2*0.5*trace((covar_k_1 + covar_k_tilde)*S_sk_list[1]) - alpha_sk_2*0.5*quad_form(mu_k_2, S_sk_list[1])


    prob = Problem(Maximize(dual_func), [alpha_k == 0.96, mu_k_1 >= 0, mu_k_2 - mu_k_1 <= 0, mu_k_2 >= - mu_k_1, mu_k_2 <= 0])
    
    print(prob.solve(solver=CVXOPT, verbose=True, kktsolver='robust', max_iters=1000))
    print(t_iter)
    covar_k_2.value = covar_k_1.value + covar_k_tilde.value
    print(is_pos_def(covar_k_1.value))
    print(is_pos_def(covar_k_tilde.value))
    print(is_pos_def(covar_k_2.value))
    
    covar_k_1_temp = np.array(covar_k_1.value)
    covar_k_2_temp = np.array(covar_k_2.value)
    covar_k_tilde_temp = np.array(covar_k_tilde.value)
    mu_k_1_temp = np.array(mu_k_1.value).flatten()
    mu_k_2_temp = np.array(mu_k_2.value).flatten()
    D_1 = np.diag(np.sqrt(np.diag(covar_k_1_temp)))
    correl_k_1 = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(D_1), covar_k_1_temp), np.linalg.inv(D_1))
    D2 = np.diag(np.sqrt(np.diag(covar_k_2_temp)))
    correl_k_2 = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(D_2), covar_k_2_temp), np.linalg.inv(D_2))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SolverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-1e1e9c7b0d73> in <module>
    109     prob = Problem(Maximize(dual_func), [alpha_k == 0.96, mu_k_1 >= 0, mu_k_2 - mu_k_1 <= 0, mu_k_2 >= - mu_k_1, mu_k_2 <= 0])
    110 
--> 111     print(prob.solve(solver=CVXOPT, verbose=True, kktsolver='robust', max_iters=1000))
    112     print(t_iter)
    113     covar_k_2.value = covar_k_1.value + covar_k_tilde.value

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in solve(self, *args, **kwargs)
    287         else:
    288             solve_func = Problem._solve
--> 289         return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    290 
    291     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in _solve(self, solver, warm_start, verbose, parallel, gp, qcp, **kwargs)
    565                     solver, warm_start, verbose, **kwargs)
    566 
--> 567         self._construct_chains(solver=solver, gp=gp)
    568         data, solving_inverse_data = self._solving_chain.apply(
    569             self._intermediate_problem)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in _construct_chains(self, solver, gp)
    508 
    509             except Exception as e:
--> 510                 raise e
    511 
    512     def _solve(self,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in _construct_chains(self, solver, gp)
    503                 self._solving_chain = \
    504                     construct_solving_chain(self._intermediate_problem,
--> 505                                             candidate_solvers)
    506 
    507                 self._cached_chain_key = chain_key

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\solvers\solving_chain.py in construct_solving_chain(problem, candidates)
     93                       "enough constraints in the problem." % (
     94                           candidates['conic_solvers'],
---> 95                           ", ".join([cone.__name__ for cone in cones])))
     96 
     97 

SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['CVXOPT']) do not support the cones output by the problem (SOC, ExpCone, PSD), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

Code referenced from: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/TT18_dissertation_Vu_0.pdf

Comment: It's like described: cvxpy makes it a conic problem involving an exponential cone. cvxopt has [no support for exp-cones](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver). But what that means for you is not so clear, as you basically just pasted a link to a 90 page dissertation and all your code.

Comment: I tried using other solvers like ECOS, which can be used to solve exponential cone constraints, but still got the same error. Would be great if you can point me in the right direction and I can look more into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objective contains PSD matrices, log_det and entr, therefore you need a solver that supports both the semidefinite cone and the exponential cone. As far as I know only MOSEK 9 and SCS can do both of these for you in CVXPY.

Strict inequalities make no practical sense because of precision in floating point arithmetic and because of issues with non-attainment. Consider minimizing x subject to x>0. Problems with strict inequalities tend to have the optimal point in the limit, which means you are incorporating the non-strict closure anyway.